# Magento 2: How to truncate orders table

Tags: magento2

I placed an order on my local. now I want to use local DB for live and I want to delete the all test order.

I know there is some table of all these orders are stored. but I don't know the name of those tables.

please provide me the name of all the tables which stores the order information

Comment: have you check my answer?

Comment: have you got answer?

Answer (score 1):

**[Note]** : Please take database backup prior to executing these queries.

I went through all tables and came up with following list of tables that should be truncated in order to clear test data:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

**Truncate order tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `gift_message`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_address_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_id_mask`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_item_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `quote_shipping_rate`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `reporting_orders`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_creditmemo_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_invoice_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_address`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_updated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_payment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_status_history`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_refunded_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_comment`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_grid`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipment_track`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `sales_shipping_aggregated_order`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_created`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tax_order_aggregated_updated`;
```

**Truncate Customer tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_grid_flat`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_log`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `customer_visitor`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `persistent_session`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `wishlist_item_option`;
```

**Truncate Review tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `review`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_detail`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_entity_summary`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_store`;
```

**Truncate Product tables**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_compare_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_price_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_relation`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_compared_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_index`;
```

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`